# Distribute a value value along time interval in array. I am using nodejs.

Tags: node.js, computer-science, data-science

Sorry if the text is confusing, I don't speak English.

My problem is:
1. I have the number of pages that was printed. 
2. The duration of printing (start time and finish)
3. I want to plot a chart by hour whith the number of pages per hour

Example:
900 pages
1:30 hous
I want this Array of hour: [600, 300]

I think this is more a mathematical problem, but I don't had a good idea to do this. The are a lot of data and i need to do a algorithm fast and optimized.

Obs: I am more interested in the logic, not in the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure that works for everything but I think is a good start.
I have made the assumption that your duration is in minutes or else I believe you can transform it to minutes.

```js
function something(pages,totalDutation){
    // pages = 900
    // totalDutation = 90
    
    var printsPerMinute = pages / totalDutation //get the prints per minute!
    var printsPerHour = Math.floor(printsPerMinute * 60) //calculate the prints made in one hour
    var countOfHours = parseInt(totalDutation / 60) //divide the total duration by 60 to get the count of hours
    var remainingPrints = (totalDutation % 60) * printsPerMinute //add the extra prints that didn't complete a whole hour.
    
    var result = Array(countOfHours).fill(printsPerHour) //create an array and fill it.
    if(remainingPrints) result.push(remainingPrints)
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the NodeJS example below to get an idea of how it can be done.
Might need a bit of fine-tuning, though.

1. Calculate the number of prints per hour
2. Make as many iterations as hours taken
3. Do (total prints - prints per hour)  as long as a > b,
   otherwise return the remaining total prints

   ```
   const getPagesPerHour = function (totalPrints, totalTime) {
       const printsPerHour = (totalPrints / totalTime) * 60;
       return Array.apply(null, { length: Math.ceil(totalPrints/printsPerHour) }).map(function (val, key) {
           if (totalPrints > printsPerHour) {
               totalPrints = (totalPrints - printsPerHour); 
               return printsPerHour;
           } else {
               return totalPrints;
           }
       });
   }

   console.log(getPagesPerHour(900, 90)); // [600, 300]
   ```